# How to retrieve url data with form action?

Tags: php, html

I want to retrieve the id of the page but the page is dynamic depending upon the id

e.g `filepath/Post.php?id=5`

Data is sent through a form action where i want to get the other pages id but i don't know how to do it.

```
echo "<form action='../PHP/Comment.php' method='post'>" . "<input class='comment' type='text' name='comment' placeholder='Add a comment'>" . "</form>"  

//then what the action does
$id = isset($_GET['id']); //trying to get the page id but it doesn't
$comment = $_POST['comment'];

//insertion into the table in the database.
mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments (id, comment) VALUES ('$id', '$comment')")
```

Comment: i dont understand anything ... Improve your question by code sample please

Comment: is this form on `Post.php?id=5` ?

Comment: yes but the id can change to whatever the post is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are better ways to do this. have you tried using a dedicated $_SESSION variable? In PHP, i cud do this:-

```
<?php $_SESSION['PAGE_ID'] = 10;?>
```

then retrieve it on the form as

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['PAGE_ID']?>
```

Comment: sorry it works all i had to do was add session_start(); on the form action script thanks.

Comment: remember not to clutter your $_SESSION with junk. when u are done with a variable, unset it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo "<form action='../PHP/Comment.php' method='post'>
<input class='comment' type='text' name='comment' placeholder='Add a comment'>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo  $_GET['id']; ?>" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>"
```

Then form processing

```
$id = isset($_POST['id']);
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments (id, comment) VALUES ($id, '$comment')");
```